# Django-Tastypie: Omit one specific object to be serialized in ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, json, many-to-many, tastypie

I have a simple Chat app. Here are my models.

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name= 'threads_partof')
    last_message_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, related_name = 'thread_to_message')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def update_last_message_datetime(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    '''
    Update Thread's last_message field when
    a new message is sent.
    '''
    if not created:
        return

    Thread.objects.filter(id=instance.thread.id).update(last_message_time=instance.datetime)
post_save.connect(update_last_message_datetime, sender=Message)
```

I use Django-Tastypie for my API. Here is an example of how my app currently works, if Steve wants to message Bill, a new "Message" object is created, where Steve is the sender. When a message object is created, it also creates a "Thread" object. In this thread, the participants are Steve & Bill.

I currently have a ThreadPreview resource.

```
class ThreadPreview(ModelResource):
    participants = fields.ManyToManyField(BasicFoodieActivityResource, 'participants', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Thread.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'thread-preview'
        fields = ['id', 'participants', 'last_message_time']
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        include_resource_uri = False
        always_return_data = True

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['last_message'] = bundle.obj.thread_to_message.latest('datetime').message
        return bundle

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(ThreadPreview, self).get_object_list(request).filter(participants = request.user).order_by('-last_message_time')
```

When I do a HTTP GET request on this resource, this is what I get back:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 1
    },
    "objects": [{
        "id": "12",
        "last_message": "Hey, Bill, you're stealing from us!",
        "last_message_time": "2013-11-07T19:27:52",
        "participants": [{
            "user": {
                "first_name": "Steve",
                "id": "28",
                "last_name": "Jobs",
                "username": "steve"
            },
            "userPic": "http://apple.com/stevejobs.jpg"
        }, {
            "user": {
                "first_name": "Bill",
                "id": "6",
                "last_name": "Gates",
                "username": "bill"
            },
            "userPic": "http://microsoft.com/billgates.jpg"
        }],
    }]
}
```

I would like to not include the user Steve when the data comes back since he is request.user. Anytime request.user accesses this data, I would like their user data to not be serialized since I already know who they are. For example, this is what I would like:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 1
    },
    "objects": [{
        "id": "12",
        "last_message": "Hey, Bill, you're stealing from us!",
        "last_message_time": "2013-11-07T19:27:52",
        "participants": [{
            "user": {
                "first_name": "Bill",
                "id": "6",
                "last_name": "Gates",
                "username": "bill"
            },
            "userPic": "http://microsoft.com/billgates.jpg"
        }],
    }]
}
```

How can I about doing this so that request.user's data is always omitted?

Comment: How does the BasicFoodieActivityResource look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The case for this question (filtering related resources)

You can use `dehydrate_participants` hook ([see docs on dehydration](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#the-dehydrate-cycle)) on `ThreadPreview` to filter participants:

```
class ThreadPreview(ModelResource):

    ...

    def dehydrate_participants(self, bundle):
        if not hasattr(bundle.request, 'user'):
            return bundle.data['participants']

        new_participants = []
        for p in bundle.data['participants']:
            if p['user']['id'] != bundle.request.user.pk:
                new_participants.append(p)

        return new_participants

    ...
```

**NB**: I could be wrong about `p['user']['id'] != bundle.request.user.pk`. `p['user']['id']` is possibly string already.

## Only when *this* resource is serialized (not when it is related)

`Resource` has a hook method [`def get_object_list(self, request)`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1014) which could be used to filter list based on `request.user`. Realisation is strateforward

```
class BasicFoodieActivityResource(ModelResource):

    ...

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        qs = super(BasicFoodieActivityResource, self).get_object_list(request)

        if request and hasattr(request, 'user'):
            qs = qs.exclude(pk = request.user.pk)

        return qs

    ...
```

Comment: When I tried this, it still returned the same results, I don't think the get_object_list from BasicFoodieActivityResource is being called from the ThreadPreview Resource. It's as if it doesn't see the get_object_list, all it sees is the class Meta from BasicFoodieActivityResource

Comment: @RiegieGodwin, true. Although it could (and should?) process related objects like a list it is totaly ignored and related objects are took one by one. I've investigated further and updated my answer.